# Using Google oAuth on WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, oauth-2.0

I trying out a small app for windows phone 7 that use Google tasks services, the problem is I'm not able to get pass to login.

I have read the all the steps given in documentation and following them
http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html#IA according to the document I need to make use of web control to login.

Is there any way I can just expect username password and get the authentication token in background?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use ClientLogin to do things in the background, but it is being replaced (slowly) and doesn't work with all Google accounts (two-step) so I would suggest you stick with oAuth2, it definitely works.

How I do it is open a `WebBrowser` control, making sure `IsScriptEnabled="true"` then point it at

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=https://www.mydomain.com/oauth2callback&scope=xxx&response_type=code
```

The really important part is the redirect url. You then wire up a `Navigating` method for your `WebBrowser` control to intercept the redirect to that url.

```
<phone:WebBrowser Name="webbrowser" Navigating="webbrowser_Navigating" IsScriptEnabled="true" />  

private void webbrowser_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Uri.Host.Equals("www.mydomain.com")) {
    e.Cancel = true;
    HandleOAuthResponse(e.Uri.Query);
  }
}
```

This will give you back the querystring google redirects with which has the `code=xxx` that you then follow the rest of the docs and exchange it for a token that will last 30mins and a refresh token to keep the authentication active.

Answer (score 2):

Have a [look at this post](http://mobile.dzone.com/news/windows-phone-7-twitter) it is about a twitter client but twitter uses OAuth too.

**EDIT**

I read more on this and it seems to be a problem because it is mandatory to use the webpage and have to user copy the access code to the app. [It appears to be hard/impossible to scrape the Webbrowser](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/70010/427354.aspx) I could not find any references to a real solution at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can scrap the webBrowser using webBrowser.SaveToString() method.

Answer (score -2):

You can actually scrape the browser URI by taking the `e.Uri.ToString()` and use the replace method to remove items not needed e.g. `thestring.Replace("http://fakeuri.com/code=","");`

Only issue I have is with the Access Token.