# use youtube gdata api in c# with microsoft windows phone 8 sdks

Tags: youtube-api, windows-phone-8

I am developing a windows phone 8 app in c#, for which i need to get some metadata from the youtube using the gdata api..

After searching for many hours, i still can't find a suitable tutorial on the net that explains how to use youtube gdata api in windows phone 8 application.I have read the official documentation but all in futile.

I need to get the list of the videos liked by the user on youtube.

can somebody provide me a nice tutorial on how to do it or just a basic functionality that at least explains how to get started with the same.

thank you

Comment: I do not understand why people close questions. Just because it was not worded well does not mean it should be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing specific about windows phone to this question. Please read the GData documentation for that.

Starting from https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_favorites you can see this is the URL to invoke for non-authenticated users: (there's also a URL for authenticated users)

> https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/userId/favorites

It appears the non-authenticated view redirects to "playlists" which can then be explored and you can get the names of playlists and video in them. For the authenticated URL you'll have to [use GData's OAuth 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901435/using-google-oauth-on-wp7) and invoke the following URL:

> https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/favorites